# Accessing the contents of an Array containing a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hashmap

I am new to ruby and trying out some examples.I have the array below that contains a hashmap.

```
    f = [{"qty"=>"5", "unit"=>"kgs", "item"=>"sugar", "cost"=>"400", "salestax"=>"0.0"}]
```

I want to print out some thing like this

5 kgs of sugar : 400 at a tax of 0.0(if you notice the content is from the hashset)

I've tried some thing like:

```
f.each 
{ 
    |m| puts m for u in m |qty,unit,item,cost,salestax| puts "#{qty} #{unit} of #{item} : #{cost} #{salestax}" 
}
```

but its not giving me what I want.

Comment: So, what's the problem here? The content is all there

Comment: You can access Hash values by their keys, e.g., `hash["qty"]`, and Array values by their indices, e.g., `array[0]`. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: To access the hash, you would just use the key, such as `f[0]["qty"]` would yield `5`. So you'd do something like, `f.each do |e|... end` and access `e["qty"]`, `e["unit"]` etc. (*e.g.*, `puts "#{e['qty']} #{e['units']}..."`

Comment: Edit your question to show what you tried. Please do not attempt to put sample code into a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f.each do |hash|
   puts "#{hash['qty']} #{hash['unit']} of #{hash['item']}: #{hash['cost']} at a tax of #{hash['salestax']}."
end
```

Seems like that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
f.each { |hash| puts "%s %s of %s : %s at a tax of %s" % hash.values }
```